# Wordpress twitter-bootstrap-3 modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, nextgen-gallery

I am using a third party plugin and pulling in the shortcode (NextGen Gallery plugin) which works perfectly - but when you click on the image it moves to a new browser window to show the full screen image. I am wondering how I wrap shortcode to show within the modal?

```
<a href="#gallery" data-toggle="modal">
                                <?php echo do_shortcode('[ngg_images gallery_ids="1" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_thumbnails" excludes="4,6" gallery_height="400"]'); ?>

</a>
```

Here is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:200px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Club video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe width="100%" height="500" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/4UnLo57BhEA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am a little stuck for ideas... :S

Comment: can you add the computed link to your question? I am wondering how this works.

Comment: http://www.allthingsai.co.uk/     Scroll to the bottom and you will see the gallery and if you click on an image it will navigate to a new window.

Comment: Sorry, but it wont work that way. You either have to edit the plugin or set it up by yourself.

Comment: @nozzleman I have set the plugin up? I have removed the modal from the code and tried using the native lightbox but for the life of me it will not work.

Comment: <?php echo do_shortcode('[ngg_images gallery_ids="1" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_thumbnails" class="ngg-fancybox"]'); ?>

Comment: i dont know where you have got the fancybox parameter from. The Documentation doesn't tell anything about it. Do you have a reference?

Comment: From here http://www.kadirrazu.info/tech/nextgen-gallery-enable-lightboxfancybox-effect/

Comment: hm, i suppose youve done all that stuff? then im out of ideas too...

Comment: I have done it yeah - I have also installed slimbox2 and apparently rthat will enable the lightbox but still nothing?